# WPF DataGrid does not display cell edits if I switch the selected row

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid and I edit a cell by double clicking into it which works generally.

But if I am in edit mode in a cell and then click with the mouse on a **different row**, then the edit will not be stored in the cell. It is empty.

But I click with the mouse on another cell in the **same row** - the cell value will be displayed correctly.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Single"  
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          CellEditEnding="DataGrid_OnCellEditEnding">            
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test" 
                  Binding="{Binding Path=SomeValue, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, StringFormat=d, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}" />                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The code-behind

```
private void DataGrid_OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e) {
    //save the changes in the DB
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: On changed of cellvalue, are you also changing the itemsource **Items** that is binded with the datagrid ?

Comment: No, I do nothing like that.

Comment: That might be the reason. Your datagrid is binded with and Itemsource, and datagrid requires the Itemsource is to be chaged.

Comment: Ok, I am going to check that.

Comment: I am mostly sure, that will solve your problem . ..

Comment: I check it. The ItemsSource is changing automatically since it is the same object. So they are in sync.

Comment: Ok.  are you sure, there is a call on Item_get() from the WPF render  after changing the value of  you grid cell?

have you also tried with the **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged** ?

Comment: I just noticed it works with string fields and the value I test with is decimal. I have to check that out. Probably an error I am not showing the code of here. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: glad that, you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was that I tested with a decimal value. So `SomeValue` is bind to a `decimal`.

```
Binding="{Binding Path=SomeValue ...
```

But the StringFormat was wrong

```
Binding="{Binding Path=SomeValue, ..., StringFormat=d, ...}" />
```

Both - removing the `StringFormat` part or changing it to

```
StringFormat={}{0:0.00}
```

fixed the problem. I did not notice before that the column value was never filled.